# Estimating a Dichotomous Item Response Logistic model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

So I'm trying to develop a logistic model. It's a little different from traditional item response models. It models one person's response on $N$ items on an exam.

$P(X_{i} =x_{i}│θ,a_i,b_i,c,d )=c+\frac{d-c}{1+exp(-a_i (θ-b_i ) )} $

where $X_{i} =1$ indicates a correct response on item $i$, and $X_{i} =0$ indicates an incorrect response. The values $a_i$ (item discrimination) and $b_i$ (item difficulty) are known. Also, $c$ and $d$ have some range restrictions:

$0 \leq c \leq 1$

$0 \leq d \leq 1$

$d-c \geq 0$

How would I go about finding the joint maximum likelihood estimates for $c$, $d$, and $θ$? If it helps, here's some example data with 5 items.

a = {0.9, 2, 1.2, 1.2, 1}

b = {-2.5, -1.3, -0.6, 0, 0.5}

x = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}

If you need more information, please let me know. Thank you!

EDIT: It's assumed that the conditional likelihood is independent. So the log-likelihood is

$\Sigma{lnP_i^{x_i}+ln(1-P_i)^{1-x_i}}$

where $P_i$ is the probability of correct response on item $i$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written down the likelihood (and/or the log likelihood) and tried to maximize it with respect to $c$, $d$, and $\theta$?

Comment: I added the abbreviated log likelihood in the question. Conditional independence is assumed. The tough part is that there are multiple parameters, so I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: In principle you would take the partial derivative of the log likelihood with respect to $\theta$ to get the MLE of $\theta$, set it to zero, and solve, etc. However, given that vanilla logistic regression does not have a closed-form MLE, I am not sure what will happen here; I have not tried it myself.